# Query about using Benchmark test singleton design pattern

Tags: java, performance, design-patterns, singleton, benchmarking

> local variable increases performance by 25 percent - Joshua Bloch "Effective Java, Second Edition", p. 283-284

I'm new to benchmark test, and i want to do a test for DoubleCheckLockingSingleton.
But the result seems like the performance of DoubleCheckLockingSingletonWithoutLocalVar is better?

I'm using https://github.com/openjdk/jmh

The benchmark result:

```
# JMH version: 1.33
# VM version: JDK 17.0.6, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 17.0.6+10-b829.9
# VM invoker: /home/repo/idea-IU-231.9011.34/jbr/bin/java
# VM options: -javaagent:/home/repo/idea-IU-231.9011.34/lib/idea_rt.jar=46469:/home/repo/idea-IU-231.9011.34/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# Blackhole mode: full + dont-inline hint (default, use -Djmh.blackhole.autoDetect=true to auto-detect)
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 10 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 10 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 10 threads, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: org.example.MyBenchmarkTest.measureWithLocalVar

Benchmark                                Mode  Cnt           Score           Error  Units
MyBenchmarkTest.measureWithLocalVar     thrpt    5    14543289.188 ±   1754652.871  ops/s
MyBenchmarkTest.measureWithoutLocalVar  thrpt    5  2238795119.169 ± 942222432.066  ops/s
```

MyBenchmarkTest file

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
public class MyBenchmarkTest {
    @Benchmark
    @Threads(10)
    public DoubleCheckLockingSingleton measureWithLocalVar() {
        return  DoubleCheckLockingSingleton.getInstance();
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Threads(10)
    public DoubleCheckLockingSingletonWithoutLocalVar measureWithoutLocalVar() {
        return DoubleCheckLockingSingletonWithoutLocalVar.getInstance();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options options = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(MyBenchmarkTest.class.getSimpleName())
                .forks(1)
                .build();

        new Runner(options).run();
    }
 }
```

DoubleCheckLocking file

```
public class DoubleCheckLockingSingleton {
   
    private static volatile DoubleCheckLockingSingleton instance = null;

    public static DoubleCheckLockingSingleton getInstance(){
        DoubleCheckLockingSingleton result = instance;

        if(result ==null){
            synchronized (DoubleCheckLockingSingleton.class){
                result = instance;
                if(result==null){
                    result = new DoubleCheckLockingSingleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class DoubleCheckLockingSingletonWithoutLocalVar {

    private static volatile DoubleCheckLockingSingletonWithoutLocalVar instance = null;

    public static DoubleCheckLockingSingletonWithoutLocalVar getInstance(){
        if(instance ==null){
            synchronized (DoubleCheckLockingSingletonWithoutLocalVar.class){
                if(instance==null){
                    instance = new DoubleCheckLockingSingletonWithoutLocalVar();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Can somebody give me a hand? thanks!

Comment: I hope you're testing this for fun, and not because you intend to use DCL somewhere? If you want a (lazily loaded) singleton, just use an `enum`.

Comment: A local variable is not a magic accelerator. When you’re still reading the field as many times as without the local variable, there is no benefit at all. When you also forget to assign the field, you create a new instance on every call, so the performance drawback is the least thing to worry about, as you don’t have a singleton anymore.